# error php bootstrap jquery y mysql Undefined index: id

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, bootstrap

soy  novato y no tengo mucha idea en esto de php con mysql, bootstrap y jquery, a ver si me pueden ayudar por favor.
Estoy intentado hacer una tabla donde paso los datos mediante un formulario y los paso mediante el método _POST para que los elimine al hacerlo me da el error *Undefined index: id*  en la consola de inspección de elemento no me da error pero me aparece el mensaje Notice: Undefined index: id in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aplicaciones/optica/optica/eliminar.php on line 6

he cambiado muchas cosas probando y me encuentro bloqueado en index.php muestro la tabla con los elementos y mediante un Modal elimino el registro y me manda a eliminar.php donde se procede a la eliminación.

Index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimun-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- estilos bootstrap onli 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    
<style>
      .container{margin-top:100px}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-horizontal" action="login.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

eliminar.php es esta :`

```
    <?php
    
    require 'conexion.php';
 
    
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    echo $id;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM personas WHERE id = '$id'";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    
?>
 
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        

        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
        <!-- ... -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">



        <!--
            <script http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"></script>
        --> 
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                <?php if($resultado) { ?>
                <h3>REGISTRO ELIMINADO</h3>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <h3>ERROR AL ELIMINAR</h3>
                <?php } ?>
                <br>
                <br>
                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-primary">Regresar</a>
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si en el `form` no hay un elemento con `name="id"` no puedes hacer esto: `$_POST["id"]`, cuando un formulario es enviado en POST se crea un array con los name y los valores de los elementos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que estás dirigiendo el **action** de tu formulario a otro archivo **login.php**  y es por eso que no recibes los datos POST en el **eliminar.php**

**Debería funcionar de esta manera**

`<form class="form-horizontal" action="eliminar.php" method="post">`

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema tal como lo indica aquí `mensaje Notice: Undefined index: id in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/aplicaciones/optica/optica/eliminar.php on line 6` cuando utilizas formularios estos mandan el nombre del elemento por lo que esta buscando un elemento con el nombre id pero no lo encuentra tu input al que quieres hacer referencia como id debe tener la siguiente etiqueta `name="id"` de esta manera el metodo `$_POST` ya sabria que elemento estas referenciando y cual es su valor.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta